# Retrieve information from Lookup field (SharePoint list) in power automate

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, lookup-column, power-automate, flow

I am trying to create an automation in power automate, triggered when a table A is edited.

Unfortunately, multiples values of that table are lookups, getting their data in other tables.

When trying to use the values from the lookups in power automate, those fields are not appearing in the "dynamic content" recommendation.

I was wondering if there is any way to retrieve the values from those fields directly?

Thanks for the help, I am new to those topics.

I can provide screenshots to explain in another if needed.

Comment: What is the data type of columns you want to get in recommendation from lookup column?

Comment: @GaneshSanap It's a single line of text (if I got the question right)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to show additional fields in lookup column settings like:

[image]

Then you can get those columns in "dynamic content" like:

[image]

---

**Note**: You can only extend below data types from lookup:

- Single line of text
- Number
- Date and Time
- Lookup (single value)

**Documentation**: [Create list relationships by using lookup columns](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-list-relationships-by-using-lookup-columns-80a3e0a6-8016-41fb-ad09-8bf16d490632)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am using that and it's now working, it's just not intuitive to have to go through those steps to make it work... Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome, glad it worked for you!